# "Об меня" or "о меня"

Tags: грамматика

There is a rule if next word begins with a vowel you should use 'oб', if not, you should use 'о'.

So, in the example from the title, it should be 'о меня', but I heard a lot of times people are saying, for example, 'ударился об меня'.

Comment: Your rule sounds somehow confusing, since 'угол' begins with a vowel, do you mean I should say 'Я ударился **о** угол', not '**об** угол'?

Comment: This rule is right, but it works only in one direction.

Answer (score 7):

Uh. :)

You know, sometimes there is no specific rule, but rather a literary tradition.

There is о, об, and обо.

To choose between об/обо there is pretty simple tradition:

Добавление гласного -о к предлогу об (об + о = обо) происходит в сочетаниях: обо мне, обо что, обо всё; обо также наряду с о (обо or о) употребляется в сочетаниях: обо всём, обо всей, обо всех.

For the first part, it will not be right to say о мне, о что, о всё. However, you can actually say о всём/обо всём (подумать о/обо всём - to take account on everything).

To chose о or об there is a longer story:

ОБ

1. "Об" употребляется вместо "о" перед словами, начинающимися с гласных а, и, о, у, э: об армии, об игре, об огне, об угол, об электричестве, об эту пору.

|| Перед словами, начинающимися с гласных е, я, ю, "об" употр. наряду с "о", причем предпочтительно "о" : о елях, о его деле, о ее деле, о юности, о ягодах. (so you rather speak о, but will not be wrong to speak об елях, об его деле and so on)

|| Перед местоимением "их" употребляется "о" наряду с "об" : о их деле и об их деле.

Перед словами, начинающимися с согласной, "об" часто, но не обязательно, употребляется в просторечии вместо "о": об доме, об тебе, а также в некоторых сочетаниях и в литературной речи, например: рука об руку; биться, как рыба об лед и другие.

- «- Вы слышали об нем? - Об ком? - Об Чацком.» Грибоедов.
- «Уж об твоем ли не радели об воспитании! С колыбели!» Грибоедов.
- «Ну вот о чем жалеть! Об лошади!» Пушкин.
- «Об ней жалели в доме все.» Пушкин.
- «Мыслил только об деле.» Салтыков-Щедрин.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about rules, but "o меня" sounds incorrect for me. Never heard or read a Russian native speaker use it. I live in Kharkiv, Ukraine and I am a native speaker of Russian.

Answer (score 1):

De-facto "об меня" is used way more frequently than "о меня". 
Try to search in Yandex or Google phrases (quotes stands for exact matching in both search engines) "о меня ноги" and "об меня ноги". This phrase is a part of very common idiom "вытирать об кого-то ноги".

You'll see that "об" form is a clearer winner.

By the way, the same holds true for "о тебя"/"об тебя", "о неё"/"об неё", "о него"/"об него" forms but not for "о нас"/"об нас", "о них"/"об них". For "нас", "них" the "o " form is prevalent.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little research and came to conclusion that in **modern** Russian correct form is "об меня".

I have found 3 sentences on 25 pages of Google with "о меня":

1. Interview with Artyom Dzyuba
2. Translation of Hopscotch
3. Translation of novel by Mayne Reid

All cases can be misprints.

Other found cases are evident misprints.

But: grammatically both cases are correct.

I can find examples in ecclesiastical texts, archaic texts, I suppose that exists example in verse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the rules, but I'm a native speaker, and this is how I see the situation.

In general both a correct: "*Об меня*" and "*О меня*". But second option ("О меня") sounds more in an ancient way. Like in fairy-tails: "*Ударился **о**земь*"[[link]](https://books.google.nl/books?id=7XhpAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=lC6_bVqVD3&sig=ACfU3U377S0vmGbNj_AkJEhx6aNLsb1Ekg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjF_abs-6zlAhXO0KQKHW-VBm8Q6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C&f=false). In a modern talk we'd say "*Ударился об землю*".

To get some clue where use what I'd suggest to use "**о**" and "**обо**" as "**about**": "*Я беспокоюсь **о** нём*", "*Ты думаешь **обо** мне*".

And use "**об**" to pointing things: "*Я ударился **об** камень*" ("*Я ударился **о** камень*" is also correct)

Answer (score -1):

На соседнем сайте [ответили](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5240/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1)

> Правила есть. Но в полном виде они весьма сложные. Полностью их можно
>   найти в "Орфоэпическом словаре" под редакцией Аванесова,
>   сопроводительная статья. Там разбору посвящено несколько абзацев,
>   перепечатывать сюда нет никакой возможности. Обратите внимание, что
>   о/об может управлять как винительным, так и предложным падежом,
>   правила употребления о/об там разные. Кстати, если еще вариат "обо":
>   "обо что", "обо всем".

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос, из приведённой вами цитаты не понятно, какой из вариантов,  приведённых автором вопроса, верен.

Comment: Я не ответил на вопрос, потому что в сообщении нет ни одного вопроса, только утверждения.

Comment: @user41264 посмотрите, пожалуйста, на заголовок - он содержит вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

both are correct, but "об меня" sounds better.

(here can be an especial situation since sound "m" produces some voice like a vowel, the same happens with "n": об ногу is better then о ногу)